# Want to load mobile version pages in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

based on this question

> [Loading NSData into a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475768/loading-nsdata-into-a-uiwebview)

Can we load mobile version view as default.

But if i use this method it automatically load desktop view in uiwebview.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to the server to recognize that it's talking to a mobile device (handset) and adapt the data.  There's not much you can do on the client-side to fix this.  The server should be able to identify your device using the User-Agent being sent along with the request.  You could add additional custom headers or parameters when you request the data; but that's not generally needed.

You may want to make sure to the `scalesPageToFit` property is set to YES on your webview.  That will often help with the page's appearance.