# UIWebView doesn't load images from protocol-relative URL

Tags: uiwebview, nsurlconnection, protocol-relative

1. Make an app with UIWebView which open a webpage with protocol-relative styles & images, such as `<img src="//example.com/image.png">` (examples for [http](http://articles.informer.com/safari-extensions-to-improve-your-web-browsing.html) or [https](https://articles.informer.com/safari-extensions-to-improve-your-web-browsing.html)).
2. Override the page loading process via your custom `NSURLConnection`, [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475768/loading-nsdata-into-a-uiwebview).

Result: it won't display the images! Though, Safari and other browsers show them correctly...

Answer (score 4):

I inspected the page opened in WebView and saw weird requests there. They looked like regular URLs, but with **applewebdata** scheme, e.g. `applewebdata://art-u1.infcdn.net/articles_uploads/2/2586/thumb/3Dtouch%20Main-665x.png`. Yay! It doesn't know the "base" scheme for the relative URL `//art-u1.infcdn.net/articles_uploads/2/2586/thumb/3Dtouch%20Main-665x.png` and gives it that Apple's fake scheme. So... the problem is here:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [m_webView loadData:webdata
               MIMEType:@"text/html"
       textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
                baseURL:nil]; /// WTF!
}
```

Solution: just save the initial URL to some `m_currentPageUrl` when starting the request, and then pass it to where it's meant to be. :)