# How to convert NSData into a pdf file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to download one pdf using `NSURLConnection` methods i got some data in `didReceiveData` method now i want to convert that data into pdf and display it on webview while downloading whole pdf so that user can view some part of pdf.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download PDF and store it locally on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226615/how-to-download-pdf-and-store-it-locally-on-iphone)

Comment: BTW, don't use the deprecated `NSURLConnection` anymore. Use `NSURLSession` (or load it directly into a web view).

Comment: Actually the file is still in downloading state.Suppose i have to download a pdf of 10mb from server. i started downloading it when i got 5 mb of data, i want to access and preview that data as pdf while the rest of the pdf is downloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can can do that by using following code:

Directly load in WebView:

```
//Pass your NSData in PdfData

[webview loadData:PdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

OR

Use `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider` to generate pdf and then load to webview:

```
//NSData to pdf
NSData *contentData               = //Your NSData
CFDataRef PDFData                 = (CFDataRef)contentData;
CGDataProviderRef provider        = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(PDFData);
CGPDFDocumentRef genPdf           = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
```

Also check: [Loading NSData into a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475768/loading-nsdata-into-a-uiwebview)